# Last-modified Date of all subscribers in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to get last-modified date of all subscribers-list in marketing cloud exact target ??

Comment: Do you mean the date the latest subscriber has been added, etc.? As you can find a last modification date in the properties tab of the all subscribers list which seems to refer to structural changes to the list, not added subscribers.

Comment: I see modified-date in properties tab, But when i tried to export it i am not able to get the modified-date in exported file. so we are trying to write a query to fetch the Data from Data View which doesn't have last modified date

Answer (score 2):

The only place it's visible is as a column in "Subscribers" tab of AllSubscribers.

Unfortunately, you cannot access the date (nor the create date or unsubscribe date) in filters or queries, which would have been very useful.